# How to save image to the Wallpaper's folder in iphone using objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can anyone tell me how to save an image from my application to the Wallpaper's folder in iphone using Xcode. The image will be downloaded from the server and displayed on UIImageView.

Can anyone help me with this...

Any code will be very helpful...

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible to do directly. As Kenny suggests you can save an UIImage to the photo album and have the user choose it from there using:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't (for AppStore apps.)

But you can save to the photo album which the users can choose as a wallpaper.

Comment: @Atulkumar: `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.